# Divergence of a Point

Tags: vector-fields, fluid-dynamics, divergence-theorem

I am currently reading a book titled Notes on Computational Fluid Dynamics: General Principles, which is provided by OpenFOAM at https://doc.cfd.direct/notes/cfd-general-principles/contents. In [chapter 2.4](https://doc.cfd.direct/notes/cfd-general-principles/conservation-of-mass) of this book, they define the divergence of a point as follows:

$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = \lim_{\Delta V \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta V} \int_{S} (\mathbf{dS} \cdot \mathbf{u})$

I understand that Gauss's divergence theorem relates the flux of a vector field through a closed surface to the divergence of the vector field within the volume enclosed by the surface and that this allows us to define $\int_V (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}) \, dV = \oint_S (\mathbf{u} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}}) \, dS$ for the divergence of a velocity field within a volume V, where V is the volume enclosed by the surface S, $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ is the outward-pointing unit normal vector at each point on S, and dS is the infinitesimal element of area on S.

However, I don't quite understand how we go from $\int_V (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}) \, dV = \oint_S (\mathbf{u} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}}) \, dS$ to $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = \lim_{\Delta V \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta V} \int_{S} (\mathbf{dS} \cdot \mathbf{u})$. Why are we normalizing the flux of the velocity field through the surface with the infinitesimal volume? Could someone please explain the process step by step or point me to a resource that does so?

Comment: The limit they take is the same as that of $\frac 1V\int_V (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}) \, dV$ when the volume $V$ goes to zero. What does that converge to?

Comment: @KurtG. Do they take the limit of both sides of the formula of Gauss' divergence theorem? If so, how do the limit and the integral on the left hand side cancel and where does 1/deltaV go?

Comment: You wrote that you understand $\int_V (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}) \, dV = \oint_S (\mathbf{u} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}}) \, dS\,.$ If so: does it matter which integral we divide by $V$ and take the limit?  When we opt for the $dV$ integral and the volume shrinks to the point $x$ is it not intuitively clear that the limit approaches $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}$ at $x$?

Comment: @KurtG. Intuitively, it makes sense that as volume becomes a point that we are left with $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}$ but I was looking for a more in depth and step by step reasoning than just pure intuition.

Comment: In this case the intuition is so overwhelming that it leads to an $\epsilon$-$\delta$-proof directly: Hint: Assume that $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{u}$ is Riemann integrable. What you should prove here is a volume-integral-version of the fundamental theorem of calculus.